# Union and universal function

Tags: c, function, unions

I'm trying to write some library in C and I have this union:

```
union { INTEGER, DOUBLE, FLOAT } Types;
typedef struct X {
    Type type;
    union { double a, float b, int c; } val;
    struct X *next;
} MyStruct;
```

I want to have insert function. For example it could be insert function to some structure like tree, priority queue or others:

```
insertInt(..., int y), insertFloat(..., float y), insertDouble(..., double y).
```

And in this way I have a lot of redundant code and it's not desirable. In other hands we have standard string conversion functions `atoi`, `atol`, `atof` located in `<stdlib.h>`, and developing library, better is duplicate code or do it in some way maybe with pointer to void and recognize type with type (in this example)?

Example of insertInt:

```
MyStruct* insertInt(MyStruct *root, int val) { 
    MyStruct *newNode = (MyStruct*)malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
    newNode->next = root;
    newNode->val.c = val; 
    newNode->type = INTEGER;
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: This is just advice, but don't cast `malloc()`. And in your example the cast is wrong too.

Comment: I wrote fast this code and I made a mistake

Comment: @UncleJone: please upvote the answers that help and click on the grey check mark below the answer score to accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid source code duplication by using a macro template for these functions:

```
#define MAKE_INSERT_FUNC(__fname, __type, __member)       \
    MyStruct *__fname(MyStruct **root, __type val) {      \
        MyStruct *newNode = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));     \
        if (newNode) {                                    \
            newNode->next = *root;                        \
            newNode->val.__member = val;                  \
            newNode->type = type;                         \
            *root = newNode;                              \
        }                                                 \
        return newNode;                                   \
    }
```

And instantiate the functions this way:

```
MAKE_INSERT_FUNC(insertDouble, double, a);
MAKE_INSERT_FUNC(insertFloat, float, b);
MAKE_INSERT_FUNC(insertInt, int, c);
```

You still need to write the declarations in your header file:

```
MyStruct *insertDouble(MyStruct **root, double val);
MyStruct *insertFloat(MyStruct **root, float val);
MyStruct *insertInt(MyStruct **root, int val);
```

I changed the API: the `insertXXX()` functions take a pointer to the list `root` pointer, so you do not need to store the return value back to the original pointer and you can test if allocation failed without clobbering the existing list.

Note that it is much less of an issue to have duplicated code (in this case with small variations), than duplicate source that tends to become inconsistent as you make modifications and fix bugs.  As an example, you could modify the template to append the new node instead of prepending it to `root`, and all insertXXX functions would get the new behavior.

Comment: One simple observation, check that `malloc()` didn't return `NULL` before `newNode->next`.

Comment: @iharob: I added it, but the API is somewhat broken as the `insertXXX` functions prepend the new node. The return value would need to be stored back to `root` and returning `NULL` would require storing to a separate location to check for `NULL` and not lose the previous `root` list.  `realloc` has the problem.  This can be fixed by passing the address of `root`.

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum Type
{
    Integer = sizeof("int"),
    DoublePrecision = sizeof("double"),
    SinglePrecision = sizeof("float")
};

struct GenericNode
{
    enum Type type;
    union
    {
        int _int;
        double _double;
        float _float;
    } value;
    struct GenericNode *left;
    struct GenericNode *right;
};

#define DEFINE_GENERIC_NODE_API_FOR(__type)                                   \
    struct GenericNode *generic_node_create_ ## __type ## _node(__type value) \
    {                                                                         \
        struct GenericNode *element;                                          \
        element = malloc(sizeof(*element));                                   \
        if (element == NULL)                                                  \
            return NULL;                                                      \
        element->left = NULL;                                                 \
        element->right = NULL;                                                \
        element->type = sizeof(#__type);                                      \
        switch (element->type)                                                \
        {                                                                     \
            case Integer:                                                     \
                element->value._int = value;                                  \
                break;                                                        \
            case DoublePrecision:                                             \
                element->value._double = value;                               \
                break;                                                        \
            case SinglePrecision:                                             \
                element->value._float = value;                                \
                break;                                                        \
        }                                                                     \
        return element;                                                       \
    }                                                                         \
                                                                              \
    __type generic_node_get_value_as_ ## __type(struct GenericNode *node)     \
    {                                                                         \
        switch (node->type)                                                   \
        {                                                                     \
            case Integer:                                                     \
                return node->value._int;                                      \
            case DoublePrecision:                                             \
                return node->value._double;                                   \
            case SinglePrecision:                                             \
                return node->value._float;                                    \
        }                                                                     \
        return (__type) 0;                                                    \
    }
DEFINE_GENERIC_NODE_API_FOR(int)
DEFINE_GENERIC_NODE_API_FOR(double)
DEFINE_GENERIC_NODE_API_FOR(float)

int
main(void)
{
    struct GenericNode *node;
    int value;

    node = generic_node_create_int_node(5);
    if (node == NULL)
        return -1;
    value = generic_node_get_value_as_int(node);
    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", value);
    return 0;
}
```

This is an *API* factory, The fact that `int` has three characters and `double` has 6 and `float` 5 was used to create the enumeration (*you could add `char`*) and the unsigned versions too. This would work as it is, and since it's apparently what you need I think it could be useful.

Note that you could pick the *get_value* function according to the type, but then you will have to declare the target variable appropriately.

Comment: is it correct for any previous version of C than C11?

Comment: AFAIK I am not using anything C11 specific.

Comment: Should CREATE_INSERT_FUNCTION(float) be DEFINE_GENERIC_NODE_API_FOR(float)? I see no definition of CREATE_INSERT_FUNCTION.

Comment: @chqrlie That doesn't matter. Please read the code carefully. Because this way the `type` member is inferred from the `__type` macro parameter ;)

Comment: Is it any other possible way to do this? I think it is not suitable to write library which is for other programmers or am I wrong?

Comment: Why is it not suitable?, it's perfect. You just hide the definition of `struct GenericNode` from them and create the *set_value* functions, also you need to create functions that don't depend on the type like adding/removing siblings, counting nodes, get the type value, etc.

Comment: iharob: OK, it's past midnight here, I missed the double quotes, but it is kludgy nonetheless, it allows support for `long long` but not for `short` that happens to have the same number of characters as `float`.

Comment: @chqrlie I don't think it's ugly at all. The idea of doing this things usally leads to code like this!

Comment: C is not my "on day" language so maybe my question is stupid. It is recommended way or exist any other "school"?

Comment: Normally [tag:c] programmers don't deal with this kind of *generic* types. It's not impossible that some program requires that, but it's unusual.

Comment: @iharob: +1, but passing the `enum` value as a second argument to `DEFINE_GENERIC_NODE_API_FOR` would be much cleaner, and having sequential enum values would allow better code generation.

Comment: @chqrlie I don't disagree, besides passing twice the same value would be an error.

Comment: @user694733 On your platform, `sizeof(char *)` is 4. And no one will include it. The solution is for `int`, `float` and `double`. Also, `sizeo(int)` can be 4 and `sizeof(float)` too for example, but with the double qoutes there is no problem, the three types will be different. And since you can stringify the argument of the macro, then it works correctly.

Comment: My bad; I does indeed give you `char[]`, not `char*`. Still, I think it is *very* error prone way to do it. It would be better to let compiler auto assign the numbers for enum and use explicit argument for macro.

Comment: I deleted the other comment so I'll add this warning separately again: I have used similar macro magic to create generic types before, and **I do not recommend it**. At least not mixing integer and floating point types: they are so different in how they function that using the same code can very easily result in hard to debug bugs.

Comment: @user694733 Trying to create a generic typing system in [tag:c] is always like this. That's why no one should do it unless really necessary. I did it once for a *.ods* file reader. The way these files work forced me to use a `union` in a way similar to this, but of course not exactly like this.